# Mesosphere success/failure callback errors

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am using the Mesosphere form package with Meteorite and I am having trouble with the onSuccess and onFailure callbacks.

For example, I simply have this:

```
onSuccess: function(formData) {
    console.log("validation success!");
    successCallback();
},
```

And I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: successCallback is not defined
```

I took this basically straight from the docs so I dont know what I am doing wrong...

https://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere#error-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. Documentation now reflects how to accomplish this properly.